# What to do in order to execute this?

Tags: java

What should I do to execute this code? I have tried to create a new class and use as a driver but it didn't work and the error message was `cannot find count`. I feel confused. Could anyone help me please?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab7Part1
{
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
  private static int[] a = {7, 8, 8, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7};
  int sum=0;
  int n=0;
  double avg = sum/a.length;
  int last=-1;
  int max=0;
  int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  int indexOfMax=-1;
  public int count()
  {
    for(int n:a){
      System.out.println(n);
      System.out.println(",");
    }//use a for-each statement to compute the number of values
    System.out.println("The number of elements in int[] a is: " + n);
    return n;
  }
  public int sum()
  {
    for(int n=0; n<a.length; n++){
      sum += a[n];
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of elements in int[] a is: " + sum);
    return sum;
  }
  public double average()
  {
    System.out.println("The avg of elements in int[] a is: " + avg);
    return avg;
  }
  public int findLast(int key)
  {
    System.out.println("Enter an integer.");
    int input = kb.nextInt();
    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
      if(a[i]==input){
        key = i;
        System.out.println("The last index of " + input + " is: " + key);
      }
      else
        System.out.println("The last index of " + input + " is: -1");
    }
    return key;
  }
```

Comment: Your average will always be incorrect, as you compute it as a field instead of doing the computation in your `average` method.

Answer (score 2):

You should add to your class a main method that would create an instance of your class.

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Lab7Part1 lab = new Lab7Part1();
    int cnt = lab.count();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you you are missing the basic.

1) You don't have Main method.

```
public static void main (String [] args){
```

2) No object creation.

```
Lab7Part1 lab = new Lab7Part1();
```

3) No call to count method.

```
lab.count(){
 //implementation of method count 
    }
```

Remember , JVM will always start execution from the main() method.

To access the method of the class you need the class instance for that you need to create object of the class.

The instance method you want to execute will start when you call the instance method implicitly .

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider declaring all of your methods static so that you do not have to make an instance of your class before running your procedures.  This serves to remind you as well that you are not making multiple unique solutions to your lab--just one.
As a side note, it is also generally bad form to have print statements in methods which return a value.  Printing is a side effect of the method, which should be focused only on returning a value for clarity.  Printing can be done in your main method.